# Find the maclaurin series of 4x/(8+x^3)

Tags: sequences-and-series, taylor-expansion

So I've done multiple attempts at this practice problem, but my result seems wrong. I'm new to this chapter, and I think I miss something fundamental, but I can't tell what. Can anybody see where I'm going wrong?

**The practice problem**

Find the maclaurin series of f(x) by using known series:

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{4x}{8+x^3}$

**Known series (from my book):**
$\left(1+x\right)^r\approx1+rx+\frac{r\left(r-1\right)}{2!}x^2+\frac{r\left(r-1\right)\left(r-2\right)x^3}{3!}$

**My attempt at solving the practice problem:**

$f\left(x\right)=\frac{4x}{8+x^3}=4x\cdot\left(8+x^3\right)^{-1}$

$8\cdot\left(1+\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^{-1}\approx8\cdot\left[1+\left(-1\right)\left(\frac{x^3}{8}\right)+\frac{\left(-1\right)\left(\left(-1\right)-1\right)}{2!}\left(\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^2+\frac{\left(-1\right)\left(\left(-1\right)-1\right)\left(\left(-1\right)-2\right)\left(\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^3}{3!}\right]$

$8\cdot\left(1+\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^{-1}\approx8-x^3+\frac{x^6}{8}-\frac{x^9}{8^2}$

$\frac{4x}{8+x^3}=4x\cdot8\cdot\left(1+\frac{x^3}{8}\right)^{-1}\approx32x-4x^4+\frac{x^7}{2}-\frac{x^{10}}{16}$

$f(x)=\frac{4x}{8+x^3}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}{\left(-1\right)^n\cdot2^{5-3n}\cdot x^{3n}}$

Comment: $1/(8+x^3)=(1/8)(1+x^3/8)^{-1}$ so you need to divide by $8$, not multiply.

Comment: @Empy2 thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I shall use the fact that if, on some interval $(-a,a)$ (with $a>0$) you have $f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$, then the Maclaurin series of $f$ is $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$. In this case, you have\begin{align}\frac1{8+x^3}&=\frac18\cdot\frac1{1+\left(\frac x2\right)^3}\\&=\frac18\left(1-\left(\frac x2\right)^3+\left(\frac x2\right)^6-\left(\frac x2\right)^9+\cdots\right)\end{align}if $|x|<2$. So, still assuming that $|x|<2$,$$\frac{4x}{8+x^3}=\frac12x-\frac1{2^4}x^4+\frac1{2^7}x^7-\frac1{2^{10}}x^{10}+\cdots$$

Comment: It is worthwhile adding that if a power series $f(x)=\sum a_nx^n$ has a positive radius of convergence, then it is MacLaurin series of $f(x).$